# Using $this when not in object context error on Laravel bootstrap pagination when using Octane

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-pagination, laravel-octane

I have setup Laravel Octane on my server with Roadrunner. Everything works fine, except for occasionally pages that use paginator throws

`Using $this when not in object context`

error. When I restart my octane server, the issue goes away for a certain time, only to reappear.

Here's a snippet of that error
[image]

And this is what my controller method looks like

```
$news = News::filter($filters)
            ->with(['tags', 'categories', 'createdBy'])
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->orderByDesc('publish_date')
            ->paginate(10)
        ;
return view('admin.news.index', compact('news'));
```

I tried clearing my cache, but still the issue persists.
I don't understand what's causing this issue. Any help will be appreciated.